# No puedo depurar javascript con vscode en firefox

Tags: javascript, vscode, depuración, firefox

Estoy intentando depurar un código de JavaScript en vscode a través de Firefox. Para ello descargue esta extensión:
[image: La extensión]

Sin embargo al ponerme a depurar me salió este error:

[image: El error]

Por lo que investigué es un problema relacionado con el depurador de firefox ya que no se conecta a el aunque si está disponible.
En el launch.json puse lo siguiente:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost",
            "type": "firefox",
            "request": "launch",
            "reAttach": true,
            "url": "http://localhost:5500",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

¿Alguien se le puede ocurrir que puede ser?